# How to Save List in SharedPreferences in Flutter

Tags: flutter

Hello all at first I want to mention that I've tried a lot of solutions here but it didn't work for me.

I bring the list from the database through the following code:

```
 var listCat = [];
  Future getdata() async {
    apiURL = '***************.php';
    var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(apiURL));
    var responsebody = jsonDecode(response.body);
    if (responsebody.length >0){
      for (int i = 0; i < responsebody.length; i++) {
        listCat.add(responsebody[i]['name']+ ':' + responsebody[i]['image'].toString());
      }
      return responsebody;
    }else{
  

    }
  }
```

As is obvious in the code above I am trying to get the name and image and this is not a problem right now I want to store this listCat in SharedPreferences until I recall it from all pages of the app

I have the following class to save SharedPreferences:

```
class APIPreferences {
  static SharedPreferences ? _preferences;
  static const _keyMuinCat = 'MuinCat';



  static Future init() async => _preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();


  static Future setMuinCat(String MuinCat) async => await _preferences!.setString(_keyMuinCat, MuinCat);



  static String? getMuinCat() => _preferences!.getString(_keyMuinCat);



}
```

Then I save what I need to save by the following line:

```
APIPreferences.setMuinCat(listCat.toString());
```

Then I can bring pre-stored data from any location where I need it through the following code:

```
CatList = APIPreferences.getMuinCat() ?? '';
```

I tried to do the following thing now to save the list in the first code above:

```
var listCat = [];
  Future getdata() async {
    apiURL = '***************.php';
    var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(apiURL));

    var responsebody = jsonDecode(response.body);

    if (responsebody.length >0){

      for (int i = 0; i < responsebody.length; i++) {
        listCat.add(responsebody[i]['name']+ ':' + responsebody[i]['image'].toString());
        APIPreferences.setMuinCat(listCat.toString());

      }

      return responsebody;
    }else{


    }
  }
```

But it didn't work. I don't really know how to deal with it.

How can I save it and then bring it to use with ListView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of:

```
_preferences!.setString(_keyMuinCat, "some string");
```

use:

```
_preferences!.setStringList(_keyMuinCat, ["some", "strings", "in", "list"]);
```

So in your code, the `setMuinCat` method needs to be:

```
static Future setMuinCat(List<String> muinCat) async => await _preferences!.setStringList(_keyMuinCat, muinCat);
```

and then you call it like this:

```
APIPreferences.setMuinCat((listCat as List).map((v) => v.toString()).toList());
```

Comment: Hi bro, can you share the full code please

Comment: @MAl : I added more context, I hope you now understand how I meant it to be?

Comment: I get this error bro / The argument type 'List<String>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.

Comment: @MAl ups, I had an error in my code. Please take the new code (use setStringList instead of setString)

Comment: Hi bro / still with APIPreferences.setMuinCat(listCat); / I get this error/The argument type 'List<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<String>'.

Comment: ah yes, you need to turn the List<dynamic> into a List<String>, I adapted the last code block, can you try again?

Comment: Hi bro / Yes I try it now  and I not get any error  but how I can get the data now? or how I can show the data ؟

Answer (score 0):

To save the list in shared preferences you need to pass as jsonEncode(yourList data) and when you will fecth the shared list you will again jsonDecode(your list)

```
await prefs.setString('YOUR KEY', json.encode(YOURMAP()));
```

Comment: Hi bro, can you share the full code please